# sqlite, best index to find smallest number greater than a given number

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with columns like so:

```
id, val1, val2 ...
```

All the id's are unique, and I want to find the row with the largest id value that is less than n for some n. I could do this with a linear search, however that is slow so I'd like to use an index. Which type of index should I use?

For example, say the id values are 1,7,22,101,444 and say for my query the n value is 17, then I want to select the row with id=7, because 7 is the largest value less than 17.

Comment: Isn't id the primary key of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id < :n ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I just tried that with a MariaDB instance in a table with `136647` entries, the execution time was `0.0280` seconds...

Comment: Thanks for telling me the query I should use. Which index should I put on the table before I use the query?

Comment: There is no choice of type.  Just do "CREATE INDEX id1 ON  table(id)`.

Comment: In most of the cases, you'd index at least the ID. I am not that deep into SQLite though, but shouldn't be ID - as a primary key - already be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite only has one kind of index. A B-tree index.

Comment: I thought you could have an index that was a hash based index, or a B-tree index. Is this not the case?

Comment: No.  Just B-tree.

Comment: ok, will the B-tree index allow me to do this query without doing linear search?